# access a hash in ruby not working

Tags: ruby, hash

after i preform this:

```
data = JSON.parse(params[:photo].to_json)
```

`puts data` gives me this `{"location"=>"russia", "userid"=>"0011"}`

however I tried all the ways of accessing this. `data[:location]` or `data["location"]` or `data[1]` I understand what a hash is, and how to work with such things in other languages, but stuck. Any help?

`data["location"]` output:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  app/controllers/sendphoto_controller.rb:5:in `[]'
  app/controllers/sendphoto_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do below it will work :-

```
puts data[0]["location"]
```

The `data` is an `array` of `hash`, like `data=[{"location"=>"russia", "userid"=>"0011"}]`.

Comment: works! will accept as soon as i can!

Comment: thank you, I missed that it is an array of hash.

Comment: For future reference, you can make it more obvious doing either `puts data.inspect` or `p data` (which does almost the same thing) instead of `puts data`. That'll output `[{"location"=>"russia", "userid"=>"0011"}]` in the above case, making the `Array` visible.

Comment: @JakobS Yes,you are true! I supposed to add this answer too,but I didn't as it is already in comment box. very true you are.